# Why isn't this function differentiable?

Tags: calculus

I was reviewing some of my grade 12 calc stuff today, and I thought of this question that I can't seem to answer.

Say I have a piecewise function $f(x) = \begin{cases} x=6, & x<1; \\ x=7, & x \ge 1.\end{cases}$

Therefore, $ \lim f'(x)_{x\to1^-} = 0 $ and $ \lim f'(x)_{x\to1^+} = 0 $. However, $f(x)$ is not continuous on x = 1, and I've learned in school that it is not possible for a function to be differentiable and not continuous. So Why isn't this function differentiable?

Comment: You have said the reason: $f$ is not continuous at $x=1$ and therefore it is not differentiable at $x=1.$

Comment: I just don't recall why a function can't be differentiable and not continuous. It makes sense in most cases, but here the slopes of both parts are the same.

Comment: The slopes are both the same *near* the point $x=1$, but *at* the point $x=1$ there isn't a slope at all.

Comment: What is $f'(1^-)=\lim_{x\to 1^-}\dfrac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1^-}\dfrac{6-7}{x-1}?$

Comment: @PatrickStevens Ok, I think I kind of understand now.

Comment: The fact that the "sideway" derivatives exist and are equal is not enough for a function to be differentiable at a point.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not continuous at $x=1$.

By definition, a real value function $f $ is differentiable at the point $x=a $, if and only if
$$\exists l\in \Bbb R\; \;\exists \eta>0 \;:  \forall h\in (-\eta,\eta) $$
$$\;\;f (a+h)=f (a)+h\Bigl(l+\epsilon (h)\Bigl )$$

with $\lim_{h\to 0}\epsilon (h)=0$.

From here, $$\lim_{h\to 0}f (a+h)=f (a) $$
which proves that $f $ must be continuous at $x=a $.